# How many 3 digit numbers can be made using the digits 1, 1, 2, 3, and 5?

Tags: combinatorics

The answer is 33. But I don't know how to get there.

Comment: Then times the permutations 3!, eleminating repeated cases where the two ones show up.

Comment: Maybe count separately (i) the numbers with two $1$'s (it will turn out there are $9$) and (ii) the numbers with all digits distinct  (it will turn out there are $24$).

Comment: Consider the total number of permutations of distinct triplets from 1, 2, 3 and 5, namely $P_{3}^{4} = 4!$. Otherwise, we have two 1's. So in any triplet of this type, there are 3 combinations with 3 permutations. Then add to get $4! + 3^2 = 33$. Reason this out to make sure you get it and then proceed to other problems.

Answer (score 2):

Cases: 
The the number contains one copy of "1".
The number contains two copies of "1".
The number contains no copies of "1."

Try from there.